# Can't git push the package-lock.json of my react-native app after upgrading expo sdk from version 45 to 46

Tags: git, react-native, expo, package-lock.json

So, Expo Go was advising me to upgrade Expo SDK from 45 to 46. The upgrading went well and I could push my changes. However, when I run "npm install" and the package-lock.json file gets created I cannot push anymore. I created a commit with only that one file and I receive this now:

```
Enumerating objects: 6, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "testEnvironmentOptions": {
      "url": "http://localhost/"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base)"
    ],
    "cacheDirectory": "./cache",
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "./app/utils/vendor"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "statements": 30
      }
    },
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setupFile.js"
    ]
  },
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --verbose --coverage"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/ngrok": "^4.1.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@freakycoder/react-native-bounceable": "^1.0.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~9.2.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "expo": "^47.0.0",
    "expo-auth-session": "~3.8.0",
    "expo-camera": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.0.1",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-random": "~13.0.0",
    "jest-expo": "^47.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^19.0.0",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mime": "^3.0.0",
    "native-base": "^3.4.7",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "radio-buttons-react-native": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-animated-spinkit": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-dynamic-search-bar": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.0",
    "react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.1.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

If you want me to provide the 41.000-line long package-lock.json file I could try to upload it somewhere online or manages to recreate the error I'd be happy to know.

Thank you so much in advance for your time and help!

I already tried to adjust the buffer in the git config and checked if the issue is related to other files of the project. I also made sure, that my git version on Windows 11 is up-to-date and that all the files have the right permissions as well as that there are no unnecessary flags and switched from HTTPS to SSH encryption.